# How to allow cross domain content script on Firefox add-on without firing mixed content blocking errors

Tags: javascript, firefox, https, firefox-addon

I'm working on a Firefox add-on. It is a [content script](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/Firefox-24/dev-guide/guides/content-scripts/index.html) for Gmail. On the content script I make requests to a server running on localhost. On the package.json file I've [allowed cross-domain content](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/Firefox-24/dev-guide/guides/content-scripts/cross-domain.html) from localhost like this:

```
 "permissions": {
      "cross-domain-content": ["http://127.0.0.1:5000/"]
  },
```

Yet, I get a "blocked loading mixed active content” error whenever I run my add-on. I am aware that since Firefox 23, [mixed content blocking has been enabled](https://blog.mozilla.org/tanvi/2013/04/10/mixed-content-blocking-enabled-in-firefox-23/). Is there a way to get around it for add-ons? The obvious solution is to run my server on localhost with https. But I want this server to be easy to install and run by users so I would like to avoid that option, also the server is meant to be run only on localhost. I'm not getting this issue with the Chrome version of the add-on, even though Chrome also blocks loading mixed active content.

Answer (score 0):

Specifying that permission will cause the `Sandbox` (`worker` in SDK internal terms, `content script` in documentation) to simply get a new XMLHttpRequest constructor, that has more than one principal (or "origin", if you like). This will only change how to same-origin-policy is evaluated, but not how security in general and mixed-content policies in particular are implemented. That is: You still cannot do a https to http `XHR`, as you noticed.

There is no work around you can use in your content script. You could however message your main script to do the [request](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/modules/sdk/request.html) and pass the result back (again via message passing) to the content script.

Please [file a bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/enter_bug.cgi?product=Add-on%20SDK). At the very least this limitation should be documented.

Personally, I wouldn't be in favor of lifting it. Mixed-content is a security issue, except for `localhost` maybe, so any code bypassing it should be easily detectable during code reviews, like the proposed message-forth-and-back work around I proposed (stuff like that draws attention during code reviews). Or maybe just lift it for `localhost`? But that decision is up to the mozilla platform, Add-on SDK and security teams.

Comment: How could I pass a message from the content script to the main script?

Comment: RTM: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/dev-guide/tutorials/modifying-web-pages-url.html and https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/dev-guide/guides/content-scripts/communicating-with-other-scripts.html